# How to create java web service to write data to Firebase?

Tags: java, web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We are creating an Android app and web app using Firebase 3.0.0. Right now both these clients are writing data directly into Firebase database.

We wish to avoid this by introducing **Web Services** component in between. This component will write data to Firebase, and it will be consumed by Android and Web (or iOS in future) apps.

We have decided to develop web services using Java, we found [Firebase JAR for JVM](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/changelog.html).

There are no Firebase tutorials to implement such a component.

Can we use this JAR for creating web services in Java? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the new Firebase, you can use the server SDK from this documentation page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup. Then start accessing the Database by following the instructions here:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start

Comment: Thanks for pointing to those links. Is this the right architecture (introducing web services component between clients and Firebase)? or should we keep writing data to Firebase from every client (Android and Web) separately?

Comment: I typically don't put a server *between* the app and the Firebase database, since I'd lose a lot of the (realtime) value of the database that way. My favorite approach is to put the server *behind* the database as in pattern 2 in this classic [blog post on Firebase application architectures](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html)

Comment: Agree, however we will be introducing web services component only for writing data to Firebase. Clients will continue using Firebase's feature for getting realtime data. I hope this should not create any issues. What is your opinion?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen A tutorial on setting up the firebase for web developement using jsp or servets will be really helpful.